# How to Add Sign-in-with-X standard for Tezos Ecosystem

Tags: signature

**Problem**

How can we connect the core team？Currently Sign-in-with-X (SIWX) is a new standard for
users to sign off-chain services，proposed by Ceramic network and SpruceID. We need to support this standard, so users can login with Tezos wallet to make signatures using a session key pairs, without popup their Metamask every time. This is quite helpful to socialFi applications around Tezos ecosystem. Please check EIP-4361 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4361

**How to implement it**
Ceramc requires us to summit the first step, to add a CAIP-122 spec for Tezos namespace, similar to how they did for Solana: https://github.com/ChainAgnostic/namespaces/pull/28. Make sure it specifies signing algorithm there.

Once we make it, they will add support in frontend-SDK and backend-node for verification of SIWT(with-Tezos). I am quite unfamiliar with Tezos wallet stardard and hope one developer from the ecosystem can help us to summit the PR.

Another useful links:
https://github.com/spruceid/siwe
https://github.com/ChainAgnostic/CAIPs/blob/master/CAIPs/caip-122.md    https://github.com/ChainAgnostic/namespaces/tree/main/tezos

Comment: This question is not a directly technical question for Tezos. Please open a discussion on https://forum.tezosagora.org/